# Send data from a different Class to the main UI-Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

could somebody tell me how I can send data from a different Class (not an High-level class e.g. not an Activity, Service ... etc) to the UI-Thread? To be more concrete in my App I have a class which connects to a server returning a JSONObject from a Thread. From that point I want to send back the JSON to the UI-Thread (My Activity). I've read something about Handler and Looper but this is very confusing for me specially because the most examples are based on the fact that the data transfer occurs in 2 Threads in the same Class. I would like to have the steps with a code snippet to know where and what I should implement. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific Thread-implementation in Android for just that. The [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) lets you do something on the UI-Thread before and after the execution in a background thread. It is mainly used for calculating something in the background and then updating the UI or to display some kind of dialog while the background thread works.

I find it fairly simple to use.

Comment: the point is the class that I'm talking about is a kind of Library. I have to use it at it is. I know about the AsyncTask. Also the Class is too complex for me to change it. The easiest change that I can do is to use an Handler. But as I said is a little bit confusing. Therefor I need a help. Many thanks despite...